# Seamonkey does not start on Debian Stretch

Tags: bash, debian, seamonkey

I downloaded Seamonkey 2.48b1 and tried to install it as mentioned on the web site (after controlling prerequisites):

> tar jxvf seamonkey-2.48b1.tar.bz2

I am the owner of the folder and its content.
In the linux console, when I go to the seamonkey directory and type `./seamonkey`, I get the message:

> -bash: ./seamonkey: No such file or directory

I am not fully skilled on Linux, and I don't understand how it can't find the file which is actually there. The issue is not related to Stretch, as the behaviour is the same with Jessie. The issue is also the same with version 2.46.

In which log file can I search for the reason of this failure?

How can I get this working?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SU , i have download seamonkey from here https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/seamonkey/releases/2.48b1/linux-x86_64/en-US/ , untar the tarball then `cd seamonkey && ./seamonkey` , It work fine on debian stretch.

Comment: You can install seamonkey through `apt` https://wiki.debian.org/Seamonkey

Comment: Thanks for the indication about wiki.debian.org, but it ends with 'E: Unable to locate package mozilla-build-seamonkey'

Comment: But the other solution is working find ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The seamonkey file is an executable one, that means already compiled. Since you decompressed but not really installed the package, seamonkey is not in the path of executable files. That is why you need the dot before the slash, because the dot resolves the actual path until the working directory.

You can add a repository as indicated in [Ubuntuzilla: Mozilla Software Installer](https://sourceforge.net/p/ubuntuzilla/wiki/Main_Page/) to make sure you have the latest compatible version.
 However, decompression as you did should work as long as the seamonkey file is compatible. The highest seamonkey version compatible with GTK2 is 2.48; later ones require GTK3 where still you have issues in several distributions.
 Any library program called at run time should be installed in your system.
 Please note that running simultaneously both Firefox and Seamonkey on the same user account/profile could have some issues. Its is better to install Seamonkey in a second user account. Also, I would add the ubuntuzilla repository in directory:-

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d